# How to install old version google-chrome on heroku?

Tags: google-chrome, heroku

I'm in the process of deploying an application on Heroku that requires an older version of Google Chrome (103.0.5060.53 for example) for its functioning. In my local environment, I can easily specify the version of Chrome I want to use, but it seems like Heroku is posing a bit of a challenge in this regard.

In an attempt to specify the required Chrome version, I've created an Aptfile in the root directory of my project with the following content:

```
google-chrome-stable=103.0.5060.53
```

This approach, however, has not proven to be successful as of yet. Every time I try to push my project to Heroku, the build fails with the following error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

This leads me to believe that the package manager is having trouble finding the specific version of Google Chrome that I want to install. I am wondering if I need to add a specific repository for older versions of Google Chrome, or if there is something else I might be missing.

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, and would sincerely appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community. How can I successfully install an older version of Google Chrome on Heroku?

Thanks in advance for your help.